# How to test IF each cell in array meets criteria and use only values(cells) in same row to compute

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I have two problems.

1. I just realized using averageif on divisions do not give me the correct average value and I have to change the formula in thousands of cells. I cannot use Find and Replace (Ctrl+H) because I have to change multiple different segments withing formula and not all of them are the same formula. (For example, some look for name, some look for size and some look for item#). Is there an efficient way to fix them?
2. My new formula is getting a bit too complicated for me and I am not sure why it is not returning value for me. What I have on first cell of the array is this:
   =IFERROR(IF(INDIRECT("D"&ROW(A1)&"!$M$8:$M$11='750㎖'"),INDIRECT("(60*SUM(D"&ROW(A1)&"!BB8:BB11))/(SUMPRODUCT(D"&ROW(A1)&"!BI8:BI11,D"&ROW(A1)&"!BO8:BO11))")),"")
   I used to have this and was working but returning wrong value(obviously cuz I was using AVERAGEIF() for divisions):
   =IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT("D"&ROW(A1)&"!$M$8:$M$11"),"=750㎖",INDIRECT("D"&ROW(A1)&"!$BC$8:$BC$11")),"")
   Now, after I fixed it, it is not returning any value.

I'm using INDIRECT and ROW to point to different sheets from D1 through D31.
I want it to to (60*(sum of BB))/(sum of BI * sum of BO). (For BB,BI,BO only where D meets criteria on the same row)

Please help my brain is not big enough for so much thinking.

OLD:
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT("D"&ROW(A1)&"!$M$8:$M$11"),"=750㎖",INDIRECT("D"&ROW(A1)&"!$BC$8:$BC$11")),"")
NEW:
=IFERROR(IF(INDIRECT("D"&ROW(A1)&"!$M$8:$M$11='750㎖'"),INDIRECT("(60*SUM(D"&ROW(A1)&"!BB8:BB11))/(SUMPRODUCT(D"&ROW(A1)&"!BI8:BI11,D"&ROW(A1)&"!BO8:BO11))")),"")

---

This is where I got to after tinkering with the formula:
=IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'D"&ROW(A1)&"'!$E$60:$E$63"),"*홈스타*"),(60*SUM(INDIRECT("'D"&ROW(A1)&"'!$BB$60:$BB$63"))/(SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("'D"&ROW(A1)&"'!$BI$60:$BI$63"),INDIRECT("'D"&ROW(A1)&"'!$BO$60:$BO$63")))),"")
P.S. This one is from a different cell but it's basically doing the same thing -> Looking for "text","size", or "ERP#" to look up if a product has been manufacturing for Day(1-31) and calculate stuff by pulling up certain numbers from the same day and the same machinary(which is by Row numbers vary from 4-91, in this case 60-63)

Comment: I don't think anyone is capable of understanding your formula without formula auditing. Did you already try this? It can heavily clarify what's going wrong.

Comment: what is formula auditing?

Comment: In your menu, at the top of your screen, choose "Formulas", you get a list of possibilities, one being "formula auditing". One of them is "Evaluate Formula", which can execute your formula step by step. This is very useful for understanding how a formula works and in case of problems you can use this to find out at which step the problem occurs. You can also "Trace Precedents" in order to verify if you are using the correct data as input parameters and more.

Comment: @Dominique Thank you! I have been editing the formula and I went through step by step check up. It shows all the right numbers until If(TRUE,number1/number2,""), and then poof I get a #div/0 all the sudden at the last step. I will edit original post and put new formula at the end.

Comment: that Korean word is supposed to have * asterisks at the beginning and at the end. I don't know why it is erased as I posted. And I am sorry for the messy post. I do not know how to put them separately as this is my first post.

Comment: Oops: asterisks are used for text formatting: a single asterisk puts a text in Italic, while two asterisks put a text in bold. If you want to show an asterisk (without text formatting), you need to put `\*` (I've already edited your question, you might have a look).

Comment: @Dominique Oh I see. Thanks! So with all the other parts being correct, why will it return #div/0 at the end? I've checked numerous times and my workbook is never returning 0 as denominator.